# Customizing json output for enumerations using spay-json-shapeless

Tags: json, scala, shapeless, spray-json

Spray-json-shapeless works fine for me for general cases. What I'm looking for is a way to extend the given functionality the output from enums in a special/customized way. Maybe there is an easy way how do do this. I'm new to all of this stuff and it is really hard for me to figure out.

At the moment I use a method similar to the spray ones, called `enumFormat(enum)`. It contains the code for reading/writing JSON. It has to be specified for every enum, so I want to get rid of this.

It would be nice if it could work the same way as for case classes.